# HTML Form Submits the Default Text Instead of Making the Field Blank

Tags: php, html

I want to have my web submit not send me the default txt in the fields if someone leaves it blank.  I am not a super coder and have spent hours trying to get it to work today and need to work on other code sections.

```
<form action="{SUBMIT_FORM}" method="post">

<input type="text" class="input-field"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '*First Name : (Required Field)';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '*First Name : (Required Field)') {this.value = '';}" name="{lead_first_name}" id="{lead_first_name}" value="*First Name : (Required Field)"/>

<input type="text" class="input-field"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Last Name :';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Last Name :') {this.value = '';}" name="{lead_last_name}" id="{lead_last_name}" value="Last Name :"/>

<input type="text" class="input-field"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '*Email : (Required Field)';}" onfocus="if (this.value == '*Email : (Required Field)') {this.value = '';}" name="{lead_email}" id="{lead_email}" value="*Email : (Required Field)"/>

<input type="text" class="input-field" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Phone :';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Phone :') {this.value = '';}" name="{lead_home_phone}" id="{lead_home_phone}" value="Phone :"/>

<input type="submit" class="sbt-btn" value="Submit"  onclick="{SUBMIT_SCRIPT}" />


{VALIDATE_SCRIPT}
 </form>
<small>*We promise to never share, rent or sale your personal information.</small>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all avoid inline HTML event handlers as long as you can.

Second, you may want to use input placeholders (HTML5) instead of setting values:

```
<input type="text" name="{lead_first_name}" placeholder="First name" />
```

for those browsers like IE (9 and earlier versions) that doesn't support `placeholder`, you can do something like [this](http://viget.com/inspire/a-better-jquery-in-field-label-plugin).

Comment: Is there a way to get the txt to disappear when clicked and come back if txt was not entered?

Answer (score 3):

Try to place default values in "placeholder" attribute instead of "value".

Comment: Note, this will only work for HTML 5 and thus only for the most modern browsers.